# No of subsets of a given set.

Tags: combinatorics

A set S has 100 elements.(any  100 different number) Find the no of subsets which have atleast 50 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Pair every set with its complement, and treat the subsets of size $50$ seperately.